# SELECT который возвращает каждую n-ую запись

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sqlite, postgresql

Добрый день! 
Есть селект в системе, на основе этого селекта строится график.

Данные в таблицу постапуют 2 раза в секунду. При этом соответсвенно график строит 7200 значений в час. Такая точность необходима для системы, но не для графика. На нем становиться невозвожно что-то прочитать. Для графика оптимально будет значение каждые 20 минут. **Т.е как организовать селект, чтобы он брал только каждую 2400 запись?** 
В голову прирходят только идеи с временными таблицами, но не могу понять как реализовать код :(

Код основного селекта

```
 BEGIN  
    select Coun_W = a.Count_W,
           DateTime=a.DateTime,
           Consumption = (a.Diff_Count_W/a.Diff_Count_AP)*1000000,
           OrderNo = b.OrderNo,
           ProductNo = b.ProductNo,
           Value = b.Value,
           Brand = b.Brand,
           BrandName = b.BrandName,
           LinkUp = b.LinkUp,
           KDF= b.KDF,
           StartDate = b.StartDate,
           CompletionDate = b.CompletionDate

      FROM ( SELECT * FROM [AcetateWeight].[dbo].[WeightCounter] where Equipment IN (@Equipment) AND Diff_Count_AP>0 and Diff_Count_AP is not null
    AND DateTime 
    BETWEEN DateAdd(Minute,450,(@DateTime))  AND DateAdd(minute,1170,(@DateTime))) as a

      inner join 

      (SELECT * FROM [AcetateWeight].[dbo].[AW_FilterPOActuals] WHERE /*DAY=@DateTime AND Shift=@Shift and*/ KDF=@Equipment) as b
      ON 
    a.DateTime >= b.StartDate AND a.DateTime<= b.CompletionDate 

   END
```

Comment: вам точно нужно решение под 5 различных движков баз данных?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Высчитайте номер записи (или возьмите готовый, если он у вас есть), и выберите те записи, у которых номер нацело делится на 2400:

Для готового номера:

```
... WHERE ID % 2400 = 0
```

Для построения номера по DateTime

```
;WITH allrecords AS (
     -- тут ваш запрос
),
rowsWithNumbers AS (
    SELECT *,
    -- вместо DateTime - нужную колонку
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DateTime) as RowNumber allrecords
)
SELECT * FROM rowsWithNumbers
WHERE RowNumber % 2400 = 0
```

но вообще, если даты у вас  уникальные, можно было бы ограничится получением записей где минуты равны 0, 20 или 40.

Comment: Проблема еще в том, что данные могут идти в базу из одного источника, а могут сразу из 4. Но решение придумал. Делаю rank as ID по дате, а потом WHERE ID %2400 = 0

Comment: @lion295 rank - rownumber - по дате - это и есть решение из моего ответа. ведь даже готовый код привел. не обязательно было придумывать его заново :)

Comment: просто немного проще, как мне кажется, сделал :) Но ваш ответ меня направил на путь истенный )
select 
   RANK() OVER (ORDER BY DateTime ASC) AS ID,
....

from ...
where ID %2400 = 0

Comment: @lion295 учтите что `RANK` выдаст одинаковые значения для одинаковых DateTime. и может оставлять дырки. т.е. он может выдать 2398, 2399, 2399, 2401. `row_number` надежнее.